# Is GridGain Off Heap feature available in community edition?

Tags: gridgain

Subj, why I'm asking, because it ./ggvisor.cmd tells me, that Off Heap memory is not changed even when I change it in config, as described here `http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/Off-Heap+Memory`
Could you, please, provide a proof link, as I haven't found that information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you used command "node" and seen NODE metric "Non-heap memory maximum".
You should use command "config".

For example, I configured off heap cache:

```
<bean class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheConfiguration">
 <property name="name" value="oh_partitioned"/>
 <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
 <property name="memoryMode" value="OFFHEAP_TIERED"/>
 <property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="#{1024L * 1024L * 1024L}"/>
</bean>
```

Then I started node and visorcmd and enter "config" command and got output about node configuration, one of the part of that output is about my cache:

```
Cache 'oh_partitioned':
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Mode                                      | PARTITIONED                        |
....
| **Off-Heap Size**                         | 1gb                                |
....
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hope this help.
In next release we will add this information in "cache" command.

Answer (score 3):

Offheap functionality is enabled in the community edition.

Please refer to the GridGain [OffHeap documentation](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Off-Heap+Memory) for information on how to enable it.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitriy, for your response. I followed your link, while configuring off heap memory (OFFHEAP_TIERED). I've provided offHeapMaxMemory & memoryMode. However, Visor tells me "Non-heap memory maximum     | 304mb", and that is not true, cause I've tried to create 4g off heap memory. Have you tried to do the same in community edition? Documentation doesn't tell, if it is for community or enterprise edition